# How to left-align CCMenuItems?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

#### Situation:

Using cocos2d's CCMenuItem and CCMenu classes I am creating a menu in the manner shown below.

#### Problem:

The menu items are center-aligned. I want them to be left-aligned (*Meaning the x-coordinate of say the first letter of each item would be about the same*)

#### Question(s):

How do I do left-align CCMenuItems? **Bonus points if you can tell me how to also left-align multiple CCLabelTTF items to a given x coordinate..*

```
CCMenuItemFont *newGame = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"New Game" target:self selector:@selector(onNew:)];
CCMenuItemFont *loadGame = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Load Game" target:self selector:@selector(onLoad:)];
CCMenuItemFont *options = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Options" target:self selector:@selector(onOptions:)];

CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems: newGame, loadGame, options, nil];

menu.position = ccp(160.0, 220.0);
[menu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding: 28.0];
[self addChild:menu z:1];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try to set the coordinates manually

like for iPad:

```
newgame.position = ccp(200,150);
loadgame.position = ccp(200,0);
options.position = ccp(200,-150);

[newgame setAnchorPoint:ccp(2,2)];
[loadgame setAnchorPoint:ccp(2,2)];
[options setAnchorPoint:ccp(2,2)];
```

Comment: Thought that 'position' is for the center of the item in cocos2d.